# Grey area on iPhone hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, hover

In the below example, when I tap any grey rectangle, the entire container that it is nested in turns grey.

Using `alert()` helps notice this moment. You need an actual iPhone to test this (or perhaps the simulator).

http://jsfiddle.net/EHE9L/5/

Can this be prevented somehow? Why does the entire parent `DIV` go grey for a second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to set "-webkit-tap-highlight-color" in your CSS so that it is transparent:-

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

See the [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-gray-highlight-when-tapping-links-in-mobile-safari/) post on this.